# How to use cards for results instead of dropdown menu? NgbTypeAhead

Tags: html, angular, typeahead, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have an auto-complete search bar using bootstrap typeahead and angular as shown below: [image]

But I would rather change the dropdown menu into a separate container that contains a list of cards in two columns beneath the search bar as suggestions instead of a drop down menu.

```
<form class="search_issue" style="width: 1000px;">
      <ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
        <div class="row" style="width: 1000px;">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <a id="search_label"><i>{{r.type }}</i></a> &ensp; {{ r.name}}
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </ng-template>

      <input id="typeahead-template" placeholder="Search for your issue/request/project/platform/team/application" type="text" class="typeahead form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt" [inputFormatter]="formatter" name="Search" />
       <button type="submit" (click)="redirect(model)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

     </form>
```

How would I go about getting rid of the dropdown all together and customize my own suggestions container? I am pretty new to Angular and bootstrap so I am not sure how to go about this. I have tried looking up how to do this but I have not found anything on how to get rid of the dropdown menu using ngbTypeahead. Any links on how to do so would be greatly appreciated. I am going to change all the styling attributes once I get the format I want, so the `style=""` statements can be ignored.

Is there maybe a way to use resultTemplate?